# How to find out which view in a stackview underwent an animation

Tags: swift

I have a view that contains a stackView. The view is triggered on long gesture recognizer. I then use hittest to animate the contents of the stackView.

My view with the stackview is defined as follows:

```
    lazy var starContainer : UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 182, height: 36))
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        view.addSubview(starStack)
        starStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        starStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 1).isActive = true
        starStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 1).isActive = true
        starStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -1).isActive = true
        starStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -1).isActive = true
        view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.height / 2
        
        // Set padding
        let padding : CGFloat = 2
        starStack.spacing = padding
        starStack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: padding, left: padding, bottom: padding, right: padding)
        starStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        
        // Generate shadow
        view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0.4, alpha: 0.4).cgColor
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 8
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 4)

        for index in 0...4 {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            if index == 0 {
                imageView.tag = 5009
            }
            imageView.tag = index
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon_starred")
            imageView.tintColor = UIColor(hex: Constants.Colors.secondary)
            starStack.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
            arrayStar.append(imageView)
        }
        
        return view
    }()
```

I have then added a long gesture recognizer and whenever it detects a change then I move the views within the stackview individually:

```
@objc func showStars(gesture : UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
      if gesture.state == .changed {
            let pressedLocation = gesture.location(in: self.starContainer)
            let fixedYLocation = CGPoint(x: pressedLocation.x, y: starContainer.frame.height / 2)
            let hitTestView = starContainer.hitTest(fixedYLocation, with: nil)

            if hitTestView is UIImageView {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    let stackView = self.starContainer.subviews.first
                    stackView?.subviews.forEach({ (imageView) in
                        imageView.transform = .identity
                    })
                    hitTestView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -50)
                })

            }
        }
```

My question is how do I get the imageView tag that's been populated in the stackview?

Note: This animation is similar to the emoticons for a Facebook post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking about this the wrong way. Your showStars method uses the call `starContainer.hitTest()` to figure out which view the user long-pressed. At that point, you know which view you are about to animate. Just remember that view.

Comment: That's right. So what I tried doing was tagging the image view and then trying to get the tag via:  `print(stackView?.subviews.first?.tag)` but it keeps coming up as 0 despite setting a tag for the image when arranging it in the stackview.

Comment: Ah never mind. I figured out what you meant. I am new to hit test. Thanks.